# How to cache nuget packages for all projects in Azure Pipelines using Cache task

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, .net-5

I'm using following step to perform solution level caching:

```
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/packages.lock.json'
    restoreKeys: |
       nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
       nuget
    path: $(NUGET_PACKAGES)
  displayName: Cache NuGet packages    

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore using package.lock.json'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreArguments: '--locked-mode'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

However, in the `Post-job: Cache NuGet packages` there's warning:

> ##[warning]The given cache key has changed in its resolved value between restore and save steps

I've realized it's because also lock files copied to output direcotries */bin/release/net5.0/packages.lock.json files are picked when resolving key.

How to I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed by using following pattern in key:

```
key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**'
```

Comment: I tried this but it complains about `##[error]System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No matching files found for pattern: **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**`. Instead I am using `key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"'`. (I don't understand what different this makes -- other than that it works.)

Comment: seems like you don't have package.lock.json are not in the repository (either the files are ignored or missing).
Your key does not update cache when package references in our project changes.

Comment: This key pattern is also used in the documentation (as of 2024): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/caching-nuget?view=azure-devops